# C# Add Icon To ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, controls, icons, toolstrip

I have a ToolStripMenuItem in my program. I also have an icon on my computer, for simplicities sake lets say its path is

```
c:\myicon.ico
```

How can i make the ToolStripMenuItem use this icon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SomeToolStripMenuItem.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\myicon.ico")
```

Answer (score -3):

ImageSource="c:\myicon.ico"

Comment: the ToolStripMenuItem doesnt have an ImageSource property :S